# Create a variable of another variable (json, getJson method)

Tags: jquery, ajax, each, getjson

I have the following viable as an example: "ratioSize": "LP555/123**17** Z ABCD"

in my each function inside my getJson call:

```
 $.each(data.infoData, function (i, item) {
                // console.log(Rating); works just fine
                //console.log(stockNumber ); works just fine

            var Rating = this.tireRating;
            var stockNumber = this.SN;
            var ratioSize = this.TS
            var NEW_VARIALBE_I_NEED = the last 2 number of the FIRST PART of ratioSize, so in this case it is 17


        });
```

any ideas of how I can make that into one of my variables? I'm totally lost here

Comment: What format are those strings going to be? We can potentially take a substring, or we can go for a regular expression match!

Comment: I am going to produce list items from there.  The list items ID would be that new variable

Comment: Sorry, what format are the ratioSize strings going to be? Always 2 letters, 3 digits, slash, five digits, space, one letter, space, four letters?

Comment: My bad, trying figure out and understand it as I go.  It will always be the last 2 number of the first part of the string. But yes, it should always be in that format I showed you, the 2 parts the one letter, and four letters.  Those could be numbers.  But the first part will always be in the same format

Comment: Okay, cool. Well, as long as the position and length of that "17" substring remains constant, then we can simply grab a substring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the position and length of the "17" string doesn't change, we can simply grab a substring:

```
var ratioSize = "LP555/12317 Z ABCD";
var result = ratioSize.substring(9, 11);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking, in order to get the characters you want, do this:

```
var Rating = this.tireRating;
var stockNumber = this.SN;
var ratioSize = this.TS
var ratioSplit=ratioSize.split(' ');
var variable=ratioSize.slice(ratioSplit[0].length-2,ratioSplit[0].length);
```

variable is now 17 from your example.